# Docker not found after restarting on Ubuntu 18

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-machine

Hello I'm stuck with an issue with docker. After forcing my laptop to shut down, docker which was working fine before now spits out the following error

> docker-compose build && docker-compose up
>
> dev_db uses an image, skipping
>
> Building dev_server
>
> ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon - you might need to run `docker-machine start default`.

I get an error on running docker-machine start default (both with sudo and without), and as I try to create a new machine with docker-machine create default, I run into the following. docker itself is still installed as I can see the commands as I enter docker.

> Running pre-create checks...
>   Error with pre-create check: "VBoxManage not found. Make sure VirtualBox > is installed and VBoxManage is in the path"

sudo service docker restart results in the following

> Failed to restart docker.service: Unit docker.service not found.

and `sudo docker ps`

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

and `systemctl status docker.service`

> Unit docker.service could not be found.

I also tried restarting my laptop and logging in and out again. I'm really puzzled by this and I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Docker is installed but the daemon is not!
There are many reasons why the devil may not be running
Maybe is storage driver

Try this steps first

Disable Docker service:  `sudo systemctl stop docker.service`

And then start Docker Daemon (overlay driver): `sudo docker daemon -s overlay`

Then edit /etc/default/docker file and add the option:

`DOCKER_OPTS="-s overlay"`